# Plot markers if markers not already plotted/circle those missing

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please let me know if I don't describe this well enough.
I have a plot where markers are determined by:

```
buy[zscore(ratios)>-1] = 0
sell[zscore(ratios)<1] = 0
buy[:251].plot(color='g', linestyle='None', marker='^')
sell[:251].plot(color='r', linestyle='None', marker='^')
```

However, I am also plotting markers on another graph based on:

```
buyLO[zscore(ratios)>-.85] = 0
sellLO[zscore(ratios)<1] = 0
buyLO[:251].plot(color='g', linestyle='None', marker='^')
sellLO[:251].plot(color='r', linestyle='None', marker='^')
```

and:

```
buyUP[zscore(ratios)>-.85] = 0
sellUP[zscore(ratios)<1] = 0
buyUP[:251].plot(color='g', linestyle='None', marker='^')
sellUP[:251].plot(color='r', linestyle='None', marker='^')
```

The markers themselves plot fine. What I would like to do (if possible) is:

1) Plot the markers that differ from:

```
buy[zscore(ratios)>-1] = 0
sell[zscore(ratios)<1] = 0
```

in a different color for the other 2 cases and

2) Circle where the markers that are missing from:

```
buy[zscore(ratios)>-1] = 0
sell[zscore(ratios)<1] = 0
```

would be for the other two cases.
I have zero clue how to do this, or if this is even possible.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'missing from'? Are you talking about markers that don't satisfy the `zscore` conditions?